# Get the top value of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Context: To give context, I am trying to create a graph with the months as the labels and the number of applications as the dataset.

My code:

```
$apps = Application::whereBetween('created_at', [
        Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
        Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
    ])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('M');
    })
    ->toArray();
```

returns

```
array:3 [▼
 "Jan" => array:2 [▶]
 "Feb" => array:1 [▶]
 "May" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

I want to create an array that produces this result:

```
['Jan', 'Feb', 'May']
```

I have tried using array keys, values, etc without any joy.

Comment: Do you only want to select the newest date with the SQL, or are trying to filter with PHP?

Comment: I just want to select the month names. To give context, I am trying to create a graph with the months as the labels and the number of applications as the dataset.

Comment: What about using `array_keys` did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for only  month list then you can use `selectRaw` and `groupBy` in query

```
  $apps = Application::whereBetween('created_at', [
                Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
                Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
            ])->selectRaw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month,count(*) as total')
           ->groupBy('month')
           ->pluck('total','month')->toArray();
```

For getting months and count list separately

`array_keys($apps)`  and `array_values($apps)`

Comment: This works, thank you - But is there a way I can still have access to the count of items inside each month so I can use it for the dataset in the graph?

Comment: @PaoloResteghini updated answer, try once

Comment: Thanks again! I can add on toArray() which gives me this: https://i.imgur.com/OHOTcUT.png

My code now looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/FKFJpcZ.png

How is best to access it in the dataset?

Comment: @PaoloResteghini do you want month and count separate array ?

Comment: I am thinking it may be the better option now!

Comment: for months list array_keys($month) and for count array_values($month)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235154/discussion-between-paolo-resteghini-and-john-lobo).